# How can I replace an Image, that's within a button, with a text/title to show instead of the image?

Tags: swift, xcode, image, timer

Basically I'm trying to setup a timer that begins to count once I click on the button. I set an image for the button and I would like the timer to replace the image and display the count, but I cannot get the image to dismiss and for the text to take it's place. Here are some relevant snippets...

```
 timerImage.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
        timerImage.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        timerImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeClock), for: .touchUpInside)


        view.addSubview(timerImage)}


        //MARK: - Stopwatch
    @objc func timeClock(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(Action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    @objc func Action(){
        timerDisplayed += 1
        timerImage.titleLabel?.text = String(timerDisplayed)
    }
```

Comment: You also might need to cleanup the image

Answer (score 0):

hey the issue is with timerImage.titleLabel you should use timerImage.setTitle

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var timer :Timer?
    var timerDisplayed: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Challenges"), for: .normal)
              button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
              button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeClock), for: .touchUpInside)
    }



        //MARK: - Stopwatch
    @objc func timeClock(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.Action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            self.button.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        }
    }


    @objc func Action(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timerDisplayed += 1
            self.button.setTitle(String(self.timerDisplayed), for: .normal)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This actually helped, but I noticed that a part of the title is actually cut off. For example,  it'll display the numbers from 1-9, and when it comes to double digits, it's just cut off the second digit...

Comment: just increase the width of the button in storybord